# Concise syntax on a single table to collapse columns using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

**TABLE:**

```
  +--------+-------------+-------------+
  | TIME   |   TYPE_X    |   TYPE_Y    |
  |--------|-------------|-------------|
  |  T1    |   VAL_X_1   |   VAL_Y_1   |
  |  T2    |   VAL_X_2   |   VAL_Y_2   |
  +--------v-------------v-------------+
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
  +--------+-------------+-------------+
  | TIME   |   TYPE      |     VAL     |
  |--------|-------------|-------------|
  |   T1   |   TYPE_X    |   VAL_X_1   |
  |   T2   |   TYPE_X    |   VAL_X_2   |
  |   T1   |   TYPE_Y    |   VAL_Y_1   |
  |   T2   |   TYPE_Y    |   VAL_Y_2   |
  +--------v-------------v-------------+
```

What I came up with uses `UNION ALL` (which works)

```
(SELECT 
  `TIME`,
  'TYPE_X' AS TYPE,
  `TYPE_X` AS VAL
  FROM
  T WHERE ...)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT `TIME`,
  'TYPE_Y' AS TYPE,
  `TYPE_Y` AS VAL
  FROM
  T WHERE ...)
```

However, the repeated `WHERE` clauses and size of the query are a problem as I deal with more fields. I'm trying to get to a concise query.
Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Are you sure in your wished result for T1 is VAL_Y_2 ?

Comment: I don't follow - what do you want in the output?

Comment: @echo_Me typo. fixed.

Comment: @Alexander The second table shows the desired output. Clarified above.

Comment: if you go the join way, don't you then need a big conditional if for choosing which column you select for each joined table? that wouln't be neither concise nor readable

Comment: This is wreaking of either poor DB design or trying to be lazy in either SP programming or how your application handles the data. Either turn the schema into a key/value pair linked to a time, OR write an SP that processes multiple queries and returns the result how you want to see if. A single query is not really going to make it more efficient, just harder to read

Comment: if i could, i would make your current concrete table the one generated with a query, while putting your desired result as real table data.

Comment: @guido This is a far simplified case. I have several more fields and using something like the one generated as the primary table is going to make it very large, with a lot of duplicate data.

Comment: are you row-modelling those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  TIME,
  if (temp.row_n=1,t.TYPE_X,t.TYPE_Y) as TYPE,
  if (temp.row_n=1,t.TYPE_X,t.TYPE_Y) as VAL
from t,
     (select 1 as row_n
      union
      select 2 as row_n) temp
```

Comment: This is way better (and seems faster). I'm going to go with this query. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i may give this solution which will give you the needed result and easy to understand and also easy to manage it to add later some fields AND even mor faster!.

```
  select time, type , val 
  from(
    select 
      TIME,
      CASE when TYPE_X = 'VAL_X_1' OR TYPE_X = 'VAL_X_2' then 'TYPE_X'  end as TYPE,
      CASE when TYPE_X = 'VAL_X_1' OR TYPE_X = 'VAL_X_2' then TYPE_X end as Val
    from Table1 
  UNION
   select 
     TIME,
     CASE when TYPE_Y = 'VAL_Y_1' OR TYPE_Y = 'VAL_Y_2' then 'TYPE_Y' end as TYPE,
     CASE when TYPE_Y = 'VAL_Y_1' OR TYPE_Y = 'VAL_Y_2' then TYPE_Y end as Val
    from Table1
  )t
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae502/1)

Comment: @DarkCthulhu wish this will help you.

Comment: But it isn't possible for me to switch on the `VAL_Y_1`, since the table I showed is only representative. But I understand the general approach using CASE.., so +1.