# How to transpose this table in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, crosstab, transpose

I have this table:

```
 lnumber |    lname       |           bez_gem              
---------+----------------+------------------------------
       1 | name1          | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
       1 | name1          | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
       2 | name2          | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.
       2 | name2          | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
       3 | name3          | Mainleus
       3 | name3          | Weismain
       4 | name4          | Weismain
       4 | name4          | Mainleus
```

The code for the query is:

```
WITH double AS (
SELECT
    partnumber,
    bez_gem
FROM accumulation a, municipality b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
        AND EXISTS (
             SELECT 
                lnumber 
            FROM mun_more_than_once c 
                WHERE a.partnumber=c.lnumber)
        ORDER BY partnumber)

SELECT
    landslide.lnumber,
    lname,
    bez_gem
FROM double, landslide
    WHERE double.partnumber=landslide.lnumber
        ORDER BY lnumber
```

I want to transpose in this format

```
 lnumber |    lname       |           bez_gem1        |  bez_gem2   
---------+----------------+------------------------------------------------
       1 | name1          | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.  | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
       2 | name2          | Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.  | Altdorf b.Nürnberg
```

Comment: I don't know if it can be accounted as a duplicate, but you are requesting exactly the opposite transformation of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347587/concise-syntax-on-a-single-table-to-collapse-columns-using-union-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c486e/1)

Data

```
-- drop table if exists test;

create table test (lnumber int, lname varchar, bez_gem varchar);

    insert into test values

           (1 , 'name1'          , 'Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.'),
           (1 , 'name1'          , 'Altdorf b.Nürnberg'),
           (2 , 'name2'          , 'Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.'),
           (2 , 'name2'          , 'Altdorf b.Nürnberg'),
           (3 , 'name3'          , 'Mainleus'),
           (3 , 'name3'          , 'Weismain'),
           (4 , 'name4'          , 'Weismain'),
           (4 , 'name4'          , 'Mainleus'),
           (4 , 'name4'          , 'XXMainleus')       
           ;
```

Query

```
select
  lnumber,
  lname,
  max(case when rn = 1 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem3   
from
  (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by lname) rn
  from
    test
  ) a
 group by
  lnumber,
  lname
```

Result

```
1;name1;Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.;Altdorf b.Nürnberg;
2;name2;Berg b.Neumarkt i.d.OPf.;Altdorf b.Nürnberg;
3;name3;Mainleus;Weismain;
4;name4;Weismain;Mainleus;XXMainleus
```

**Old Answer**

If you have only two possible rows for every `lnumber` (you should add this important info to your question), you can simply use `min` and `max`:

```
WITH double AS (
SELECT
    partnumber,
    bez_gem
FROM accumulation a, municipality b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
        AND EXISTS (
             SELECT 
                lnumber 
            FROM mun_more_than_once c 
                WHERE a.partnumber=c.lnumber)
        ORDER BY partnumber)

SELECT
    landslide.lnumber,
    lname,
    min(bez_gem) as bez_gem1,
    max(bez_gem) as bez_gem2
FROM double, landslide
    WHERE double.partnumber=landslide.lnumber
group by
    landslide.lnumber,
    lname
ORDER BY lnumber
```

If you have possibly more than two rows for every `lnumber` and you really need crosstab, there is a lot of questions regarding crosstab in PostgreSQL on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)). As an alternative you can try the following approach.

Because this is one-time analysis, you can easily get maximum number of unique `bez_gem` values:

```
select 
  landslide.lnumber, 
  count(distinct bez_gem) cnt 
from 
  <<some_data>> 
group by 
  landslide.lnumber 
order by 
   cnt desc limit 1
```

Then you can use:

```
select
 landslide.lnumber,
 lname,
 max(case when rn=1 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem1,
 max(case when rn=2 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem2,
 max(case when rn=3 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem3,
 max(case when rn=4 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem4,
 max(case when rn=5 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem5,
 ... up to cnt ...
from(
  select
   landslide.lnumber,
   lname,
   bez_gem,
   row_number() over(partition by landslide.lnumber) rn
  from
   <<some_data>>
 ) a
group by
  landslide.lnumber,
  lname
```

For your data and 5 possible values it would look like:

```
WITH double AS (
SELECT
    partnumber, bez_gem
FROM 
  accumulation a, municipality b
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
  AND EXISTS (
              SELECT lnumber 
              FROM mun_more_than_once c 
              WHERE a.partnumber=c.lnumber)
ORDER BY 
  partnumber
)

select
  landslide.lnumber,
  lname,
  max(case when rn=1 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem1,
  max(case when rn=2 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem2,
  max(case when rn=3 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem3,
  max(case when rn=4 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem4,
  max(case when rn=5 then bez_gem end) as bez_gem5
from (
  select
      landslide.lnumber,
      lname,
      bez_gem,
      row_number() over(partition by landslide.lnumber) rn
  from 
      double, landslide
  where 
    double.partnumber=landslide.lnumber
) a       
group by
  landslide.lnumber,
  lname
```

Comment: I have possibly more than two rows for every `lnumber`.

Comment: How many rows? Does this need to be dynamic (underlying data are changing and so should number of columns) or is this one-time exercise?

Comment: This is a on-time exercise. I've extended the table in my question. I tried the cross tab (like in the exmaple you gave me), but I have a lot of distinct municipalities and I don't know how to use the `VALUE` expression in this case.

Comment: I added another possible solution, without using crosstab extension. I guess this will slow, but should work.

Comment: When I use your edited query, for every lnumber (lname) there are three bez_gem with the same values for every row and to many results (526 instead of 66). You forgot an alias on the subquery and lname was ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of difficult to write correct sql without test data. Added working solution, added SQLFiddle example.

Comment: Finally it works when I use the row_number subquery like a `WITH` query. After that I can use the `CASE WHEN` expressions. I'm wondering if there a problems using `row_number` in subqueries like in your approach, in general?

Comment: `row_number` should work fine in any subquery. However, it does not work together with `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you always have two `bez_gem` per `lnumber`, you can simply use:

```
SELECT lnumber, lname
     , min(bez_gem) AS bez_gem1
     , max(bez_gem) AS bez_gem2
FROM   test
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61f85/1)

Note that the order of peers is undefined in your question. Collation rules (alphabetical order) decide in my example.

For an *actual cross tabulation* you would use the `crosstab()` function from the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html). But your table is missing a category name (no indication which row holds `bez_gem1` and which `bez_gem2`). Explanation, details and links:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)